# Populating dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, null, nsdictionary

I've got a simple function which compiles a dictionary from two others according to the last. 
Compiler shows no errors, but after execution `resultDict` is empty. In debug all vars `counter`, `type.1` and `tempDict` have correct not-nil values.

```
func compileBaseFromCSV(original: [Int:[String]], headers: [Int:String]) -> [Int:[String:[String]]] {
    var resultDict = [Int:[String:[String]]]()
    var tempDict = [String]()
    var counter = 0
    for type in headers {
        for object in original {
            tempDict.append(object.1[type.0])
        }
        resultDict[counter]?[type.1] = tempDict
        counter += 1
    }
    print(resultDict)
    return resultDict
}
```

What's wrong with this code? Thanks!

Comment: Do not misuse the array enumerator for dictionaries (although it's working because the dictionary is represented by a tuple). The recommended enumerator is `for (key, value) in dictionary {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you never set `resultDict[counter]`, you need something like:

```
if resultDict[counter] == nil {
  resultDict[counter] = [:]
}
```

before pushing values into it.

But there seem to be a few more issues in your code (e.g. should tempDict get reset?). Use the debugger to step through your code and look at the values and check how they change (and whether that matches your desire).